# How to identify a new line in edittext dynamically?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've set the attribute in xml 
`android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"`
so the traditional way of parsing the text and finding `\n` does not work well to dynamically identify a new line.
What can be done in this situation?
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a new line or a word wrap?  A newline can absolutely be found by looking for a \n.  This character will be sent if the user hits the enter key.  If you're looking for where it word wraps to a new line-  I doubt that you actually want or need that.  Unless you're writing your own textfield and need to draw out the text, there's not a lot of reason to do so.

Comment: Not sure there's really a good way of doing this that will work in all scenarios. Could you maybe provide a little detail of the effect you're going for and perhaps there is a better solution?

Comment: I'm looking to find where the line word wraps.

Comment: The scenario is that, I'm building a text editor.. and I'm implementing a search feature. Now, I'm parsing the text for a match case and highlighting it using `BackgroundColorSpan`, but only highlighting isn't enough, I need to scroll through as the user press next/back button (with different highlight color ofcourse). So I'm calculating the scroll pixels dyanmically using lines count to the text and line's height.